# Django try except error for 'AnonymousUser'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm just a student. I have this kind of code. I use the Try except condition for the user_membership. But i wonder how can i solve the *'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable* error if the user is not login.. i tried to hide the disabled button by using user.is_authenticated but it's not working. *(Note: i think login required in BookDetail can solve this but i want it to be available even if the user is not login)*

views.py

```
def BookDetail(request, id):
most_recent = Book.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
book= get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.instance.post = book
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse("book-detail", kwargs={
            'id': book.pk
        }))
try: 
    user_membership = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
except Customer.DoesNotExist:
    user_membership = None

context = {
    'user_membership': user_membership,
    'form': form,
    'book': book,
    'most_recent': most_recent,

}
return render(request, 'catalog/book_detail.html', context)
```

and my book_detail.html

```
{% if user_membership and user_membership.user == request.user %}
        {% for content in book.pages %}
            <a href="{{ content.get_absolute_url }}" class="site-btn">Read</a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <button class="site-btn" disabled="disabled">VIP</button>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for AnonymousUser with `is_anonymous` property - you can read more in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous).

For example you can edit your code like this:

```
def BookDetail(request, id):
    most_recent = Book.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    book= get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = book
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("book-detail", kwargs={
                'id': book.pk
            }))

    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        user_membership = None
    else:
        try:
            user_membership = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            user_membership = None

    context = {
        'user_membership': user_membership,
        'form': form,
        'book': book,
        'most_recent': most_recent,

    }
    return render(request, 'catalog/book_detail.html', context)
```